# Converting an Excel to text in vb

Tags: excel, vba, reference

```
Sub SaveToCSVs()
Dim fDir As String
Dim wB As Workbook
Dim wS As Worksheet
Dim fPath As String
Dim sPath As String
fPath = "C:\Users\rshuell\Desktop\My_Excel_Files\"
sPath = "C:\Users\rshuell\Desktop\My_Excel_Files\"
fDir = Dir(fPath)
Do While (fDir <> "")
If Right(fDir, 4) = ".xls" Or Right(fDir, 5) = ".xlsx" Then
On Error Resume Next
Set wB = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fDir)
For Each wS In wB.Sheets
wS.SaveAs sPath & wS.Name, xlCSV
Next wS
wB.Close False
Set wB = Nothing
End If
fDir = Dir
On Error GoTo 0
Loop
End Sub
```

I am having difficulty referencing the "Workbook" reference for Excel, my intentions are to make a very small Excel worksheet tab delimited into a text file that is created but the name of the file is named as a excel sheet I just need to rename it as a text file. Like I said that isn't so much the issue I cant figure out the "WorkBook" or "Active Workbook" I keep seeing in the sample code I am finding and looking up how to referencing the Microsoft.Excel, I have tried to add to my project isn't working to do away with the errors in the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

edited

```
Sub SaveToCSVs()
Dim fDir As String
Dim wB As Workbook
Dim wS As Worksheet
Dim fPath As String
Dim sPath As String
fPath = "C:\Users\rshuell\Desktop\My_Excel_Files\"
sPath = "C:\Users\rshuell\Desktop\My_Excel_Files\"
fDir = Dir(fPath)
Do While (fDir <> "")
If Right(fDir, 4) = ".xls" Or Right(fDir, 5) = ".xlsx" Then
On Error Resume Next
Set wB = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fDir)
For Each wS In wB.Sheets
wS.SaveAs sPath & wS.Name, xlCSV
Next wS
wB.Close False
Set wB = Nothing
End If
fDir = Dir
On Error GoTo 0
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Your posted code is doing the opposite of what you describe you want to do.

Comment: converting excel to text?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the string variable `path` to a value in your code.
You must both `Dim` and `Set` the variable `ResultWB`

There may be other problems.

Comment: This is some sample code I used to show "WorkBooks" or what I have seen "Active WorkBooks". I understand the paths "c:\...."  I'm just not seeing why I get errors on the "Excel Workbooks" is it a reference or do I need to declare a variable?

Comment: @LuannSlate  Where have you **Set** an instance of `ResultWB`??

Comment: Students   '        Dim WB
        Dim ThisWorkbook
        Dim WorkBooks
        Dim xlDoubleQuote  '

Comment: I'm still having an error with            Workbooks.OpenText(FileName:= _
            TxtFileName _
            , Origin:=437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
            xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
            Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="|", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), _
            Array(2, 1)), DecimalSeparator:=".", ThousandsSeparator:=",", _
            TrailingMinusNumbers:=True)

Comment: "the errors in the code" - what errors are you seeing, and on which line(s)?